# Django Admin - Inline forms missing after overriding get_form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to hide some fields from a Form on Django Admin if the logged user is not a super user. This is what I came up with:

```
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(RestauranteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            form.base_fields.pop('approved')
            form.base_fields.pop('day_of_the_week')
            form.base_fields.pop('photo')
        form.label_suffix = ''
        return form
```

This does indeed hide the necessary fields, but for some reason the admin also stops rendering  my inlines if the user is not a super user. As far as I can see this method should have nothing to do with the inlines. Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just exclude it before calling the parent method

Hope it helps

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:              
       self.exclude = []
    else:    
       self.exclude = ['approved','day_of_the_week','photo']

    return super(RestauranteAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```